# Nativescript SSDP discovery

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to discover devices connected to local network via SSDP, was trying to use node-ssdp lib but got error regarding dgram not found, my understanding is that this dependency is not supported by nativescript,
is there any alternative, either how to do socket udp/tcp or if there is already existing lib.

Was thinking of using Android Wifi P2P discovery but i think better have something platform independent.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is a plugin already, you may want to write one by choosing appropriate native libraries on each platform.

Comment: I was hoping for a nodejs solution as it is not specific to platform, like we have the http module do we have access to raw socket ? The actual code for ssdp is not that complex except that nodejs default dgram for creating socket is not supported